# How do i change the column names from existing to a row below in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: gg]

Here is the current dataframe as shown in the pic. above.

i want new dataframe with columns as month1, month2, month3.... month5

here is the pic of output dataframe that is required

[image: enter image nnnnn here]

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:
`df = df.drop(0, axis=0)`

or inplace, like:
`df.drop(df.index[0], axis=0, inplace=True)`

Comment: Is this what you need @Pramod Bhat? :)

Comment: comment by @Vitalizzare solves it perfectly

Comment: Sorry, what comment? :)

Comment: @Pramod Bhat, is your question resolved? :)

Comment: yes its resolved,  but the solution posted by @Vitalizzare was deleted here by him

Comment: Ah okay :) Good luck my friend!